# Accuracy loss in vector tiles generated with ST_AsMVTGeom

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles

I generate vector tiles using data from Postgres DB and PostGIS function `ST_AsMVTGeom`.
I'd like to take advantage of overzooming so that I can only create vector tiles say for Zoom Level 15, and then overzoom the tiles to Zoom Level 19/20. I noticed that in some cases for detailed building outlines/land parcels the joining points loose their topological consistency once rendered into the vector tile and overzoomed. Things improve if I tile cache for larger scale, but this means I need more tiles. Is there any way to basically generate better quality/accuracy vector tiles for smaller scale so they better overzoom? Are there any methods to prevent such gaps? Could this be a result of over-simplification by the internals of `ST_AsMVTGeom` where I basically loose some points which causes the lines 'too straight' ?

[image: Gaps in lines at L15]

Ideally above should look like this after overzooming, but I could only achieve this after tile caching at Zoom Level 17:

[image]

Comment: That belongs to the nature of MVT vector tiles https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/guides/vector-tiles-standards/#encoding-geometry. You can get better resolution by increasing the extent value https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html but MVT geometries are always approximated. Use GeoJSON or GML if data needs to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging it looks like this is fixed/improved in PostGIS 3.2.0 (I was on 3.1.1). According this release note:

https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/NEWS

> #4149, ST_AsMVTGeom now preserves more of original geometry's details at scale close to target extent.